# JQueryUI Sortable functionality is not working with lightbox2

Tags: jquery-ui-sortable, lightbox2

JQueryUI Sortable functionality is not working with lightbox2 
http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/

Getting error message $(...).sortable is not a function

I have checked and it seems js sequence is not an issue here